# Problem with the legend with scale_color_discrete() function in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I've this data

```
tempi_k_random <- c(2.849072363496035E-6,4.884230846336759E-6,7.420560612989667E-6,9.320163959989317E-6,1.125275640739933E-5,1.3818609943264999E-5,1.5799511999414483E-5,1.79927469933985E-5,1.958275275649878E-5,2.1785199360099794E-5,2.4198109784553963E-5,4.54269327069883E-5,6.518881674784684E-5,8.52658233138289E-5,1.0445134492757438E-4,1.268194860165957E-4,1.4795886846906084E-4,1.7116724615770838E-4,1.9454743217185282E-4,2.095390879427764E-4,4.1366770908908134E-4,6.202640042883945E-4,8.379609645905531E-4,0.0010454638386975343,0.001188950746965453,0.0014212418300653593,0.0017239767156862745,0.0018250641025641023,0.002074198717948718,0.0040149999999999995,0.0059812500000000005,0.008516666666666665,0.011816666666666666,0.0189875,0.020087499999999998,0.0222125,0.016399999999999998,0.019649999999999997,0.0282,0.04525,0.0523,0.06235,0.0798,0.09570000000000001,0.10475,0.12225,0.1352)

tempi_k_cinque <- c(2.185171516292494E-6,3.688659557278267E-6,5.086848744974997E-6,6.550152577270055E-6,8.190041618674074E-6,9.569229015801014E-6,1.130849767469026E-5,1.2768555980732062E-5,1.4900814742468114E-5,1.5916628540808872E-5,1.7213466225813496E-5,3.214082728715961E-5,4.5726078618563776E-5,6.314850708691957E-5,8.436387207939846E-5,9.751538176472509E-5,1.0571751299724081E-4,1.1758304250994831E-4,1.3748931047676842E-4,1.480619766765244E-4,3.119003987090575E-4,4.3609348952131457E-4,6.194213313568152E-4,7.484261873392308E-4,8.79766911150425E-4,0.0010233251633986926,0.001126502976190476,0.0013468323343323345,0.001551022727272727,0.002741190476190476,0.004115000000000001,0.0052,0.0084125,0.0105125,0.01695,0.019,0.013525,0.016325,0.02135,0.03055,0.038,0.045149999999999996,0.05875,0.07305,0.0888,0.1039,0.09995)

tempi_ndieci <- c(2.375526248273769E-6,4.256132067044228E-6,6.042428977111871E-6,8.615698869627676E-6,9.95753073736447E-6,1.1776845215643598E-5,1.3660545425457787E-5,1.5924493501608036E-5,1.7668195352664178E-5,1.9221459566688867E-5,2.045119723829764E-5,3.811749152074419E-5,6.038099988218772E-5,7.483761391315114E-5,9.55648261718686E-5,1.1421521459312587E-4,1.353618000970425E-4,1.593224149232047E-4,1.664030090266135E-4,1.8585104947233018E-4,3.6222878593326967E-4,5.813731241132015E-4,7.396324821243827E-4,8.994984672166082E-4,0.0011234896715603237,0.001304954374293577,0.0013452083333333332,0.0016280505952380952,0.0018492628205128204,0.0037657738095238096,0.00477625,0.007389583333333334,0.010470833333333334,0.0153375,0.0194375,0.0166,0.0146,0.01645,0.022949999999999998,0.038,0.0464,0.05675,0.0742,0.08495,0.09765,0.10375,0.11015000000000001)

tempi_nmenoc <- c(2.28491345365468E-6,3.529909336343534E-6,5.025295275675399E-6,6.514100794323373E-6,8.058699140564791E-6,9.471434112359757E-6,1.0944375376030776E-5,1.2384409686795722E-5,1.4036495365797998E-5,1.5624169208365355E-5,1.6777502364941904E-5,3.14744111238494E-5,4.5192996614103015E-5,6.243421855589104E-5,7.603017835619405E-5,8.73392281204343E-5,1.0611253966143871E-4,1.2097295470045547E-4,1.3288902062298435E-4,1.4510677837849405E-4,2.898812731152251E-4,4.287646414347314E-4,5.860436388208565E-4,7.231695424141076E-4,8.790873015873016E-4,0.0010133180684554523,0.0010897767857142857,0.001376007326007326,0.0014679807692307692,0.002784523809523809,0.004365,0.004866666666666666,0.008370833333333334,0.0112625,0.0145375,0.016237500000000002,0.014225,0.016300000000000002,0.0238,0.032049999999999995,0.0437,0.04775,0.0581,0.0665,0.08595,0.0955,0.10055)


#Input da 100 a 10'000'100
lunghezzaInput <- c(100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,2100,3100,4100,5100,6100,7100,8100,9100,10100,20100,30100,40100,50100,60100,70100,80100,90100,100100,200100,300100,400100,500100,600100,700100,800100,900100,1000100,2000100,3000100,4000100,5000100,6000100,7000100,8000100,9000100,10000100)
```

I've create this data frame

```
df <- data.frame(lunghezzaInput,tempi_k_random,tempi_k_cinque,tempi_ndieci,tempi_nmenoc)
```

and with ggplot2 library I've made this representation :

```
options(scipen=999)

gg <- ggplot(df,aes(x=lunghezzaInput, y=tempi_k_random, colour = "blue")) +
  scale_color_discrete("Tempi") +
  geom_smooth(method="loess", se=F) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=tempi_k_cinque,colour = "red"), method = "loess", se=F) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=tempi_ndieci, colour = "#3DE61A"), method = "loess", se=F) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y=tempi_nmenoc, colour = "#FFD13B"), method = "loess", se=F) +
  labs(subtitle="Analisi dei tempi di Median of Medians", 
       y="Tempo (s)", 
       x="Grandezza Input", 
       title="Median of Medians")
  

plot(gg)
```

But in this image I want to change the legend element's name.

[image]

How can I call them

```
"K = Random"
"K = n - 5"
"k = n/10"
"k = 5" ??
```

Comment: Can you try adding `labels` to `scale_color_discrete`, for example: `scale_color_discrete("Tempi", labels = c("K = n - 5", "k = n/10",...`?

Answer (score 5):

This type of problems generaly has to do with reshaping the data. The format should be the long format and the data is in wide format. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format) on how to reshape the data from wide to long format.

First, create a *named vector* of color values.
Then reshape the data, pipe directly to `ggplot` and then use only one `geom_smooth`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

tempi_names <- c("K = random", "K = n - 5", "k = n/10", "k = 5")
gg_colors <- c('#0000FF', '#FF0000', '#3DE61A', '#FFD13B')
gg_colors <- setNames(gg_colors, names(df)[-1])

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    cols = starts_with('tempi'),
    names_to = 'Tempi',
    values_to = 'Value'
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = lunghezzaInput, y = Value, colour = Tempi)) +
  geom_smooth(formula = y ~ x, method = 'loess', se = FALSE) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Tempi", 
                      breaks = names(df)[-1],
                      labels = tempi_names,
                      values = gg_colors) +
  labs(subtitle="Analisi dei tempi di Median of Medians", 
       y="Tempo (s)", 
       x="Grandezza Input", 
       title="Median of Medians")
```

[image]